While running the GIHTUB workflow file , I am getting an Error
I am trying deploy an UI service on to top of AKS using GITHUB Actions.
Run npm install
  npm install
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/http@6.1.10
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@7.2.16
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~7.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"7.2.16" from @angular/animations@7.2.16
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"~7.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/animations@">=7.0.0" from @angular/material@7.3.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^7.3.7" from the root project
npm ERR!   12 more (@angular/cdk, @angular/common, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"6.1.10" from @angular/http@6.1.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/http
npm ERR!   @angular/http@"^6.1.10" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@6.1.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"6.1.10" from @angular/http@6.1.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/http
npm ERR!     @angular/http@"^6.1.10" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-05-01T07_12_10_212Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-05-01T07_12_10_212Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I tried
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

but it did not work.

You have to show the workflow you're using, or it's impossible to figure out what's going on.

Your package.json or package-lock.json has an incompatible set of dependencies. I would suggest as a first measure to try to make sure everything is updated to the latest version. --legacy-peer-deps is a hack/workaround.
